# in R: loop through matrix files, transpose and save with new name

Tags: r

i have a list of text.files. each file contains a matrix. each matrix has to be transposed and saved again as plain text with new filename.

so far i have:

```
 for (k in dir(".")){h=t(as.matrix(read.table(k))); print(h)}
```

i don't know how save each transposed matrix in a text file and how to rename them 
by adding a prefix like :`"transposed_"` to the old file name yielding something like `"trasposed_file.name"`

i tried to find a solution but i suspect i lack the keywords to look in the right place and i also suspect that r is not the best language for this kind of job. 
i would still appreciate very much any help and if possible a solution in .

if it isn't already clear to the reader : yes i am very new in r and lost.

Comment: that was supposed to read : "if possible a solution in R". thanks again in advance

Comment: Instead of `print`, just `write.table(h, paste('tranposeds_',k,sep='',collapse='')` should create the new files.

Comment: Just as you have used `read.table` you will find `write.table` useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
filenames <- list.files()

for (i in filenames) {
  mat <- t(read.table(i))
  filename <- paste0("transposed_", i)
  write.table(mat, file = filename)  
}
```

Comment: geez, couldn't even wait for my comment to get posted :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry for the hasty answer... ;-)

Comment: thanks again. it took me 2 whole minutes to find the check mark. buy the way thanks for answering my first Question ever posted.

Comment: @user3265621 You're welcome! I wish you a good time on stackoverflow. :)